# How to change battleship grid using logicpuzzle package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, logicpuzzle

I designed the naval battle grid using the `logicpuzzle` package. I would like to make some changes, could you help me?

1. I would like to move ABCDE letters to the bottom of the grid.
2. I would like to be able to write a letter inside the green motorboat.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\let\puzzletitleformat\titleformat
\let\titleformat\relax
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
% sffamily
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\sffamily}}
% use scale and fontsize options to change size
%\begin{center}
\begin{battleship}
\placesegment{5}{2}{\ShipR}
\placesegment{1}{5}{\ShipL}
\placesegment{1}{1}{\ShipR}
\placesegment{4}{4}{\ShipL}
\placesegment{2}{3}{\ShipL}
\shipH{A,B,C,D,E}
\shipV{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{battleship}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Solution (first question): Add `\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\shipH[1]%
{%
  \LP@setrowcontents{#1}{1}{0}%
}%
\makeatother` to your preamble.

Answer (score 6):

Bobyandbob answered the first question in his comment, and I implemented that in the code below.

To place a letter inside a `\ShipL`/`\ShipR`, you can simply add a second `\placesegment` with the same coordinates, after it. For example,

```
\placesegment{5}{2}{\ShipR}
\placesegment{5}{2}{a}
```

will place the `a` on top of the `\ShipR`. If you want a simpler syntax, such as `\ShipR[a]`, you can redefine the `\ShipR`/`\ShipL` macros for example as in the code below.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\shipH[1]{%
    \LP@setrowcontents{#1}{1}{0}%
}%
\renewcommand*\ShipL[1][]{%
  \tikz[scale=\LP@BS@scale]
     \draw[scale=.36,fill=\LP@BS@shipcolor,
           path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {#1};}
      ](1,2)--(2,2)--(2,0)--(1,0) arc (270:90:1);}%
\renewcommand*\ShipR[1][]{%
  \tikz[scale=\LP@BS@scale]
     \draw[scale=.36,fill=\LP@BS@shipcolor,
           path picture={\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {#1};}
      ](1,2)--(0,2)--(0,0)--(1,0) arc (270:450:1);}%
\makeatother
\let\puzzletitleformat\titleformat
\let\titleformat\relax
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
% sffamily
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\sffamily}}
% use scale and fontsize options to change size
%\begin{center}
\begin{battleship}
\placesegment{5}{2}{\ShipR[A]}
\placesegment{1}{5}{\ShipL[B]}
\placesegment{1}{1}{\ShipR[C]}
\placesegment{4}{4}{\ShipL[D]}
\placesegment{2}{3}{\ShipL[E]}
\shipH{A,B,C,D,E}
\shipV{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{battleship}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternativ you could create `\ShipLmod{Input Text}` and `\ShipRmod{Input Text}` (with `\renewcommand*`). The text centering is not perfect (maybe we could find a better solution for that (together).

- **1.Move ABCDE letters to the bottom of the grid with:**

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\shipH[1]%
{%
  \LP@setrowcontents{#1}{1}{0}%
}%
\makeatother
```

- **2. Write a letter inside the green motorboat: with `\ShipLmod` and `\ShipRmod`**

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ShipRmod[1]{\tikz[scale=\LP@BS@scale]\draw[scale=.36,fill=\LP@BS@shipcolor](1,2)--(0,2)--(0,0)--(1,0) arc (270:450:1) node[xshift=-0.05cm,yshift=-0.37cm] {#1};}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ShipLmod[1]{\tikz[scale=\LP@BS@scale]\draw[scale=.36,fill=\LP@BS@shipcolor](1,2)--(2,2)--(2,0)--(1,0) arc (270:90:1) node[xshift=0.05cm,yshift=-0.37cm] {#1};}%
\makeatother
```

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\let\puzzletitleformat\titleformat
\let\titleformat\relax
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\shipH[1]%
{%
  \LP@setrowcontents{#1}{1}{0}%
}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ShipRmod[1]{\tikz[scale=\LP@BS@scale]\draw[scale=.36,fill=\LP@BS@shipcolor](1,2)--(0,2)--(0,0)--(1,0) arc (270:450:1) node[xshift=-0.05cm,yshift=-0.37cm] {#1};}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ShipLmod[1]{\tikz[scale=\LP@BS@scale]\draw[scale=.36,fill=\LP@BS@shipcolor](1,2)--(2,2)--(2,0)--(1,0) arc (270:90:1) node[xshift=0.05cm,yshift=-0.37cm] {#1};}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% sffamily
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\sffamily}}
\begin{battleship}
\placesegment{5}{2}{\ShipR}
\placesegment{1}{5}{\ShipL}
\placesegment{1}{1}{\ShipRmod{A}}
\placesegment{4}{4}{\ShipLmod{B}}
\placesegment{2}{3}{\ShipL}
\shipH{A,B,C,D,E}
\shipV{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{battleship}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @TorbjørnT.(+1) for your solution. Can i adapt your solution with path picture bounding box.center for positioning text input in my solution, because shifting with `xshift=0.05cm,yshift=-0.37cm` isen't nice.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Go right ahead, I stole your solution for the first part after all.  You could alternatively use something like `\node at (1.5,1) {#1};` for `\ShipRmod`, that would be about in the center of the shape. (By the way, @-pings only works for other commenters and editors of the post, so I wasn't notified of your comment.)